# How to implement multithreading in loop of api calls nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, performance, worker

I have some thousands of text objects in an array.
I want to send each text to an API and save the result into one collection and updating another collection on successful result.

Here is my implemetation,

```
let arr = [
    {
        textId: "123",
        text: "This is stackoverflow"
    },
    {
        textId: "678",
        text: "I love stackoverflow"
    }
];

let textIds = [];
for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    const result = await axios.post("API", {text:arr[i].text});
    if(result && result.status === 200){
        await db.collections("solutions").insertOne({...arr[i], result});
        textIds.push(arr[i].textId);
    }
}
await db.collections("texts").updateMany({textId:{"$in":textIds}},{"$set":{solutionFlag: true}});
```

This gives bad performance when I iterate like 10k, 20k texts. It takes around 1hr for 10k texts.
How can I optimize this code.
Will `worker_threads` work here?

Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

Worker threads are used when you need CPU intensive job concurrency. This is IO intensive concurrency. So, you can accomplish this by just using ordinary promises. You should collect promises returned by this call, and run them concurrently like this:

```
const promises = arr.map(elem => axios.post("API", {text:elem.text}));
const results = Promises.all(promises);
```

Making so many concurrent requests may not be what you want. In that case, do something like this:

```
var textIds = [];
for (var i = 0; i < n/concurrency_factor; ++i) {
    const promises = arr.slice(i*concurrency_factor, (i+1)*concurrency_factor);
    const results = Promises.all(promises);
    textIds = textIds.concat(results.map(res => res.id));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, here I have one doubt like, if any promis got failed, then for that promise I don't want to push the `textId` into `textIds` array, and also for a single api call, my result is too large document, will it not harm anything in performance? And do I not use `await` to get the result of all promises?

Comment: It sounds like you want to ignore the exception for individual promises then. So, your promise will be `axios.post("API", {text:elem.text}).then(res => res.id).catch(ex => null)` And then you can filter the array of results to remove nulls.